# Docker Compose Labling

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Does anyone know if its possible to have a docker label use a service item?

ie: take the following,

```
services:
  app:
    image: repo/my-test-app
    container_name: my-test-app
    labels:
      com.example.appname: my-test-app
```

its there some way to get the label to reference the container_name i.e:

```
services:
  app:
    image: repo/my-test-app
    container_name: my-test-app
    labels:
      com.example.appname: ${container_name}
```

Obviously that would pass a shell variable, but how do i pass container_name ??

for clarity i know there are the default labels "com.docker.compose.service" but this is just a functional example.

Answer (score 0):

i got the idea to solve it with envs.

For example you define the env:

```
MY_VAR=myvalue
```

and then you call it in you docker-compose:

```
services:
  app:
    image: repo/my-test-app
    container_name: ${MY_VAR}
    labels:
      com.example.appname: ${MY_VAR}
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but it doesn't scale to well.